# i need a query to update column transferred_to to ‘Invalid_destination’ in Storage table if transferred_to column is equal 100

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, where-clause

the query that i tried is this

```
UPDATE transfered_to
SET name = REPLACE(name,'Invalid_destination')
WHERE transfered_to in ( SELECT transfered_to
FROM Storage WHERE Invalid_destination = 100);
```

But i got this output

```
Table or view does not exits
```

so this is my table

```
                                       Storage
STORAGE_ID  MODEL   SERIAL_NUMBER   TRANSFERED_TO
50          s-1      1234211           51
```

Comment: This is really unclear. Which column do you want to update? And under which condition? If `transfered_to` is o a numeric datatype, you can't put string "invalid destination" into it.

Comment: i want to update 'transfered_to' column if its equal to 100

Comment: What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: varchar() so i try this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
update `storage`
set transfered_to = 'invalid destination'
where transfered_to = '100'
```

Note that `storage` is a language keyword in MySQL, hence a poor choice for a column name. It would be simpler to use another column name, otherwise you need to quote it.